# There is a MathJax command for the GCD. What, if any, is the command for the LCM?

Tags: support, mathjax

There is $\gcd(a,b)$, written as `$\gcd(a,b)$`. How I can write lcm(a,b),
the command $\lcm(a,b)$ gives an error.

Comment: It's strange that such common operator has no built in command already, but I guess there are too many, related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112037/why-is-lcm-not-defined-as-default. Anyway for these it is point 11. in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: @Sil I just missed this link because I typed $5040$ instead $5020$. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\operatorname{lcm}` or if you use it a lot in a given answer, `\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}` will make the `\lcm` command available, but only for that answer.

Comment: I've seen also `$\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}$` for the same functionality.

Comment: We can also talk about `\newcommand{\lcm}{\mathop{\mathrm{lcm}}}` if you want to start listing all the equivalent ways of doing that... :-)

Comment: Not really, I am sure someone has already did that somewhere (I wonder if they included `\text{lcm}` there? I wouldn't recommend that one)

Comment: @Sil I'm agree with you. But if you use `\text` in many cases it is necessary a bit of the space.